# Routing is not work with react-router-redux actions

Tags: react-router, react-routing

When use the Link, router works as expected, though i get a warning [history] pushState is deprecated; use push instead.

Using routeActions from react-router-redux does't work, url was change (http://localhost:3002/addCity), but view still the same (Home) or show error if i go to page by url for example: localhost:3002/addCity.

git: https://github.com/kirsanv43/Weather.git

reducers:

```
export default combineReducers({
  cities,
  routing: routeReducer
});
```

store config: https://github.com/kirsanv43/Weather/blob/master/app/redux/config/store.js

```
import rootReducer from '../reducers'

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const history = createHistory();
  const middleware = syncHistory(history)

  const finalCreateStore = compose(
    applyMiddleware(middleware)
  )(createStore)

  const store = finalCreateStore(rootReducer)

  middleware.listenForReplays(store);

  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
      const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers').default
      store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer)
    })
  }

  return store
}
```

Router:

```
const store = configureStore()

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
        <Route path="addCity" component={AddCity}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Component:

```
class CitiesList extends React.Component { 
  onAddCity = () => { 
    this.props.route.push('/addCity')
  };

  render() {

    return <div className="weatherContainer">
      <ul>
        <li className="listItem addBtn"><a onClick={this.onAddCity}><span>ADD CITY</span></a></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
  }

}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return { 
    route:bindActionCreators(routeActions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CitiesList)
```

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

insted createHistory need use createHashHistory from 'history'

that working for me

Comment: I had the same issue. But createHashHistory didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change  "react-router-redux" version  to "^5.0.0-alpha.8". It solved my problem